# how to grep for 'vector' but not 'std::vector'

Tags: c++, grep

I've spotted a `using namespace std;` in a common header in our code, and I want to remove it.

Consequently, I need to replace all occurrences of `vector` in my code with `std::vector`.

I need to write an expression to grep it, that ignores the following cases:

```
std::vector
// comment with a vector
"string with a vector"
```

so that I don't end up replacing them like

```
std::std::vector
// comment with a std::vector
"string with a std::vector"
```

So far, I've managed to ignore the ''std::vector'' case using the expression

```
grep "^[^:]*vector" *.h
```

But I have problems composing negations, like:

- find "***X***" but not "***YX***" nor "***Y.*X***"

can anybody help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this input

```
$ cat a
std::vector
// comment with a vector
"string with a vector"
replace this vector
```

You need to pipe grep so that they are AND. Otherwise with `egrep "condition1|condition2"` they would be OR.

```
       skip :vector        skip starting with "    skip starting with /
            ----                   -----                 -----
$ grep "^[^:]*vector" a | grep "^[^\"]*vector"   |     grep "^[^/]"
replace this vector
```

Answer (score 4):

You might call it cheating, but I'd just replace all `std::vector` by `std::fector`, replace all `vector` by `std::vector` and then replace all `std::fector` back to `std::vector`.

It's not cool, but for a one time solution it probably solves your problem faster than building a complicated expression will. Thinking about the expression alone takes longer than doing just it.

Make sure your program does not use an std::fector though :)

Comment: What I've always done is to replace `vector` with `std::vector` everywhere (and the same with `string`, `map` and anything else which might be used, and then make a last pass replacing `std::std::` with `std::`.

Comment: This doesn't catch the case of having "vector" in a string or comment though.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are using vector a *lot*, you could just remove the using declaration and manually go through the error messages. Typically you'll only need to change places where you instantiate a vector, which shouldn't be that often.

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually do this is to globally replace `\<vector\>` with
`std::vector`, then to globally replace `\<std::std::` with
`std::`.

Comment: this does not deal with vector inside a comment, nor a string, though. Not to mention #include<vector>

Comment: I'm not sure that vector inside a comment is a problem; it becomes std::vector, but that's probably OK.  vector inside a string has never been a problem for me because I've never encountered it---maybe conditioned by the types of applications I've worked on.  As for `#include <vector>`: the global replace I use is `:g!/#include/s/\<vector\>/std::&/g` (vim); you'll have to find something similar for your editor.

Comment: @GrimFandango But the goal isn't to find a perfect solution. (I've done so for similar problems once or twice, but each time it required a more or less elaborate script in Python.  The goal is to find a pretty good solution which can be implemented fast enough, and what it misses handled by hand fast enough that it isn't worth developing a perfect solution (which might take a couple of hours).

Comment: The code I'm working on is >10 million-lines, with 6000 cpp files and about 1000 header files that need to be changed. vector (and string, and find and pair, and set, and map, and so on) must be replaced automatically where possible, and NOT replaced wherever it might cause an error. I think that the 'perfect' solution is what I should aim for, otherwise a few days of manual work is needed. The perfect solution would be to create the vim command that replaces the right occurrences, also

Comment: @GrimFandango A perfect solution will require a C++ parser.  After all, `int vector;` is perfectly legal, even after `using namespace std;`.  For a code base over 10 million LOC, it may be worth it; try looking into Clang.  (Of course, if the code was written to strict guidelines, and you can be sure that it follows them everywhere, or almost everywhere, some shortcuts can be used.  But my experience with large code bases suggests that this will not be the case.)